# What documentation works with handling utxos at the Plutus Script?

Tags: plutus, smart-contract, plutus-playground, token

I am trying to make a Plutus smart contract which takes tokens locked to the contract and then on endpoint call (purchase) sends 1 to the caller and then the rest back to the contract. I cant find a distribution model for this I would assume you would have to create a new utxo out of the existing utxo and reduce it down into a single token on the script but I am very lost with this process.

I need help figuring this out so that I can create this send 1 token out of many script. A specific answer is what I'm looking for.

This is the code relevant to the problem, but it currently does not work.

```
purchaseUtxo :: ChainIndexTxOut
purchaseUtxo = case fromTxOut (scriptTxOut (Value.singleton (policyID contractInfo) (nameOfToken contractInfo) (1)) validate (Datum $ PlutusTx.toBuiltinData ()) )  of
    Nothing     ->  error ()
    Just x      ->  x

purchase ::  AsContractError e => PurchaseParams -> Contract w s e ()
purchase p=  do
    utxos <- fundsAtAddressGeq valAddress (Ada.lovelaceValueOf 1)
    let utxoMap = Map.singleton (TxOutRef (_citxTxId ChainIndexTx) 1) purchaseUtxo
        redeemer = ()
        pkh = ownPubKey
        tx       = Constraints.mustPayToTheScript () price <> collectFromScript utxoMap redeemer
        
    void (submitTxConstraintsSpending lootBox utxos tx)
```

And here is the error:

> Compilation Error, Line 148, Column 54 (jump)
>
> error:
> • Couldn't match expected type ‘ChainIndexTx’
> with actual type ‘TxId
> -> Data.Set.Internal.Set TxIn
> -> ChainIndexTxOutputs
> -> SlotRange
> -> Map DatumHash Datum
> -> Map RedeemerHash Redeemer
> -> Map ScriptHash Script
> -> Maybe SomeCardanoApiTx
> -> ChainIndexTx’
> • Probable cause: ‘ChainIndexTx’ is applied to too few arguments
> In the first argument of ‘_citxTxId’, namely ‘ChainIndexTx’
> In the first argument of ‘TxOutRef’, namely
> ‘(_citxTxId ChainIndexTx)’
> In the first argument of ‘Map.singleton’, namely
> ‘(TxOutRef (_citxTxId ChainIndexTx) 1)’
> | 148 |     let utxoMap = Map.singleton (TxOutRef (_citxTxId ChainIndexTx) 1) purchaseUtxo
> |                                                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> on endpoint call sends 1 to the caller and then the rest back to the contract

Remember, the on-chain portion of a contract doesn't do anything actively, it only validates transactions. So a more accurate way to phrase this would be, "the script only validates transactions that spend 1 ADA and return the rest to the script."

I think everything you need to write a validator you could find in the [auction code](https://github.com/input-output-hk/plutus-pioneer-program/blob/8cbc68d146c82cc95d9be44c30e049aba3774003/code/week01/src/Week01/EnglishAuction.hs#L103). Notice that it stores the current bid amount in the datum and that datum is attached to the actual UTxO with the value.

```
    ownOutput   :: TxOut
    outputDatum :: AuctionDatum
    (ownOutput, outputDatum) = case getContinuingOutputs ctx of
        [o] -> case txOutDatumHash o of
            Nothing   -> traceError "wrong output type"
            Just h -> case findDatum h info of
                Nothing        -> traceError "datum not found"
                Just (Datum d) ->  case PlutusTx.fromData d of
                    Just ad' -> (o, ad')
                    Nothing  -> traceError "error decoding data"
        _   -> traceError "expected exactly one continuing output"

    correctBidOutputDatum :: Bid -> Bool
    correctBidOutputDatum b = (adAuction outputDatum == auction)   &&
                              (adHighestBid outputDatum == Just b)

    correctBidOutputValue :: Integer -> Bool
    correctBidOutputValue amount =
        txOutValue ownOutput == tokenValue Plutus.<> Ada.lovelaceValueOf amount
```

If instead of the `close` endpoint, you have a `take distributions` endpoint, you could just do a similar check that the datum was updated and the value wasn't decremented by more than 1.

At that point, it is up to the caller to build a transaction in their own benefit. Again, the off-chain code in the above auction example could be adapted to build a transaction to claim distributions.

Comment: Thanks ill try this method

Comment: Did you have any luck?

Comment: yes I think I understand it better now thank you

Answer (score 1):

On casual search I think what you need is Ledger.TxConstraint:

https://playground.plutus.iohkdev.io/doc/haddock/plutus-ledger-constraints/html/src/Ledger.Constraints.TxConstraints.html